# Well-ordering of positive Gaussian integers under lexicographical ordering?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I am reading a paper by Richard Weimer called "Can the complex numbers be ordered?" and he makes the following claim.

Let $G^+=\{a+bi : a,b$ are positive integers $ \}$ and let $<$ denote lexicographical ordering.  It is easily demonstrated that there are an infinite number of Gaussian integers with respect to $<$ between $(a,b)$ and $(a+1,b)$ where $a,b$ are positive integers.  (I understand this sentence).  Thus, one can easily deduce that $G^+$ under $<$ is not well ordered, i.e., not every non-empty subset of $G^+$ possesses a smallest element.  (This sentence I don't understand.)

If you have a nonempty subset $S$ of $G^+$, can't you find a minimum $c$ of the real components of elements in $S$ since $a$ is a positive integer?  Then if you look at the subset $R = \{s \in S : \operatorname{Re}(s) = c\}$, won't it have a least element which will also be the least element of $S$?

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're quite right. $G^+$ with lexicographic ordering is well-ordered, for the reasons you give. In fact, your argument shows that whenever $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered sets, then the lexicographic order on $A \times B$ is a well-order (in your example, $A=B=\mathbb{N}$). This fact can be used to define [multiplication of ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic).